# Php Trigger by <input type="button"

Tags: php, html

If have this code on my website

```
<input type="button" value="Action A" id="oldladd"/>    
<input type="button" value="Action B" id="newladd"/>
```

and

```
<input id="pp" type="text" maxlength="200"  style="width: 100px" />
<input type="button" value="Change" id="poolp22" />
```

Now what i want is 
When they press "oldladd" and "Newladd" 
The "poolp22" action happens so that i bypass the textfield

Now i was thinking this code could work

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_POST['oldladd'])) {
        $potoud = $prpo[1]['price'];
        $potnieuw = $potoud + 16; 
    }
?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $potnieuw ;?>" id="poolp22" />

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['newladd'])) {
?>
     <input type="hidden" value="16" id="poolp22" />
<?php
    };
?>
```

Could someone help me figure this out

Comment: ids are not used to submit the form. none of your inputs have `name`s, so they're essentially useless at submit time - they'll be totally ignored.

Comment: Sidenote: Using `type="button"` with older versions of IE will not work. Use `type="submit"` instead to be on the safe side ;-)

Comment: mark b is correct. but in addition to fixing value attributes you need to clarify what you want. after submit, you want to change the form???? or onsubmit, you want to change form?

Comment: This thing drives me nuts, its a admin.php page with 2 functions 
i want to get to work together,
1 to update price
and 1 to change 6 value's

All i wanted was when i change the 6 value's the price updates, but i cant figure out the php file, its uses JS and other stuff :s

Comment: i can upload the whole file if you are interested

Comment: Well rob after i submit i want the price to change in the database

Answer (score 0):

Replace the type attributes Button to Submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Action A" id="oldladd"/>    
<input type="submit" value="Action B" id="newladd"/>

<input id="pp" type="text" maxlength="200"  style="width: 100px" />
<input type="submit" value="Change" id="poolp22" />
```

I think its work.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RWCC19KW

this is how my complete file would look like, i'll change the button to submit but it has been working with "button"